# Remap / to a another search function?

Tags: key-bindings, search

I there a way to remap `/` that trigger builtin search function of vim to another search `fuzzy` function and how to achieve that?

Comment: You should be able to use [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) to get a fuzzy search in your buffer content (at least that's what the [commands](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim#commands) `Lines` and `BLines` seems to do). But I don't think you can override `/` to get the same interface as the built-in search, at best you could remap `/` to start the fzf command. Note that you might also be interested by [`:h :grep`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3agrep) depeding on what you actually want to do.

Comment: @statox: I tried `map / :<fuzzy>`, doesn't work. Did I miss something?

Comment: Vim does not contain a <fuzzy> function, you would have to implement a fuzzy search yourself

Comment: @TuyenPham Yeah you probably missed something. I don't use but I don't think fzf provides a `:<fuzzy>` command. You should read the doc, install `fzf`, install `fzf.vim`, try to make a fuzzy search in the command line and once everything works you can try to create your mapping.

Comment: Thanks guys, `nnoremap / :FuzzySearch<CR>` work as expected. :)

Comment: @TuyenPham You can post an answer detailing what you installed and how you made your mapping, that could be helpful for future reader. Also another solution could be [incsearch-fuzzy.vim](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch-fuzzy.vim) which seems to do what you want, but it has a dependency and I don't know how well that works.

Answer (score 1):

I use plugin that expose `FuzzySearch` to call its function, we overwrite builtin search function of vim that triggered by press `/` by this remap: `nnoremap / :FuzzySearch<CR>`.

`nnoremap`: Only apply in normal mode, no remap allowed.

`<CR>`: Because this function need to be called before accept the next argument that is a search string, so we don't have to explicitly press enter.